# Paralelización naif

Tags: c

Me estoy interesando últimamente por la programación en paralelo (en concreto para multiplicar matrices de la manera más rápida posible).

Tengo escrito un pequeño programa que realiza la multiplicación estándar de forma "paralela", lo escribo entre comillas porque he utilizado la muy chapucera técnica de programación en paralelo que consiste en crear N procesos con fork(), con la esperanza de que el sistema operativo reparta cada proceso a un núcleo distinto (el caso es que parece funcionar, al menos haciento "top" en la terminal veo que efectivamente se ponen N CPUs al 100%).

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo de malo (en cuanto a tiempo) es hacer la paralelización de esta forma, en comparación con pthread u openMP (por ejemplo)? ¿Pierde mucho tiempo el sistema creando los nuevos procesos y luego matándolos, etc?

Comment: Hola Guillermo. ¿Has hecho benchmarks que analicen esas metricas que quieres sacar?  Con esos tests podrás sacar tus propias conclusiones... Si no, ¿has investigado en google las estadisticas?  ¿Qué has sacado en claro ?  Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Hola lois6b, por ahora solo he comparado mi paralelización naif (usando N procesos para multiplicar dos matrices cuadradas de tamaño N) con la multiplicación estándar de matrices, obteniendo tiempos de cálculo ~ N^2.2  (frente a N^3 de la multiplicación estándar). En google no he sabido como referirme a lo que aquí llamo "algoritmo naif" como para hacer una búsqueda efectiva, pero sigo en ello. Gracias por los consejos y el enlace, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿cómo de malo (en cuanto a tiempo) es hacer la paralelización de esta forma, en comparación con pthread u openMP (por ejemplo)?

Lo malo que tiene la programación en cuanto a temas de rendimiento se refiere es que no suele existir una respuesta clara.

Así, pese a lo que se explica normalmente, que las funciones inline (sustituto sano de las macros en C) son la leche porque mejoran el rendimiento, lo cierto es que su uso puede tanto mejorar el rendimiento como empeorarlo y muchas veces depende de si la función inline estropea la localidad de los datos... si la caché tiene que cargar datos nuevos con la inclusión de la función inline el rendimiento caerá drásticamente.

Y, como no podía ser de otra forma, la paralelización no se escapa a esta ambigüedad... que mejore o no el rendimiento dependerá de lo que haga concretamente tu programa y de cómo lo haga.

Así, lo primero que hay que hacer antes de lanzarse a paralelizar como si no hubiese un mañana, es medir los tiempos de ejecución para tener una base sobre la que empezar a comparar resultados.

Si resulta que los tiempos son excesivos y no son válidos para el alcance del proyecto el siguiente paso es analizar dónde se está consumiendo el tiempo de ejecución. Puede que el tiempo se esté consumiendo simplemente en hacer reservas de memoria y liberándolas un poco más tarde... en este caso por mucha paralelización que pongas los tiempos van a seguir siendo malos y la primera solución pasaría por reducir el número de reservas de memoria que se realizan.

Otro cuello de botella puede estar en la lectura de datos o en el uso de una arquitectura de código mal elegida.

El caso es que si después de corregir todo eso se llega a la conclusión de que la única vía posible para que los tiempos cuadren con los pedidos es paralelizar ahora toca pensarse cómo y dónde paralelizar.

Está claro que el hardware que mejor paraleliza el cálculo sobre matrices es la tarjeta gráfica... pero tiene una penalización importante y es la comunicación entre el micro y la tarjeta para llevar los datos a tratar y para recuperar los resultados ... (las *pantallas de carga* de los juegos se usan mientras se nutre a la tarjeta gráfica de las texturas, matrices y objetos necesarios durante la partida).

Otra posibilidad de paralelización sería aprovechar los diferentes núcleos del procesador... en este caso tenemos que tener presente que si usamos memoria compartida y tenemos que recurrir al uso de *mutex* y *semáforos* el rendimiento final **puede** no ser de nuestro agrado... como siempre todo dependerá de los requisitos de la aplicación y de nuestra la implementación que hagamos.

Y es que claro, si decidimos no usar **mutex** y porque hemos preparado todo para que los procesos no puedan pisarse la memoria podemos llegar a experimentar tiempos de ejecución más largos si, por ejemplo, los procesadores acaban peleándose por el uso de los recursos:

- solo existe un bus de datos para todos los procesadores
- el contexto de cada proceso debe cargarse cuando el hilo despierta y descargarse cuando el procesador decide dormirlo (demasiados procesos *matan* el rendimiento del equipo)
- La caché (algo vital para que los tiempos sean óptimos) se puede ver perjudicada si diferentes procesos trabajan con diferentes regiones de memoria
- ...

Así que ahí queda. La paralelización puede ser buena o mala y depende de cada caso en concreto. También hay que tener en cuenta que si bien es cierto que una buena paralelización puede mejorar los tiempos de forma brutal esto no siempre tiene que ser así... si tu algoritmo cumple con los requisitos sin usar paralelización mi consejo es que te la ahorres para cuando haga realmente falta.